# Index 9 error after xlWhole although content is there

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to search the whole column A of an Excel spreadsheet in an Outlook VBA macro with the following code and have the value from column K output in the same row.

The following code works fine:

```
ColumnA = InputBox("Please Column A value.")
ColumnB = wb.Worksheets("fsgksdhgks").Range("A:A").Find(ColumnA).Offset(0, 10).Value
MsgBox (ColumnB)
```

However, the following code, which I actually need because I only want unique values (e.g., I don't want to find ABC when I enter BC), throws Error 9 Index errors.

```
ColumnA = InputBox("Please Column A value.")
ColumnB = wb.Worksheets("fsgksdhgks").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ColumnA, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 10).Value
MsgBox (ColumnB)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can't be both vb.net and vba. removed vb.net tag.

Comment: Do you mean error 9, or error 91? For error 9, that would suggest your worksheet name is incorrect for the specified workbook. Error 91 would suggest the find operation failed - you should always test that before trying to use the found cell.

Comment: I mean "Runtime error 9: Index out of valid range". The worksheet is correct, otherwise the first call would not work without errors. With my first call I only get ABC as cell when I search BC. But I want to find BC directly, which also occurs in column A.

Comment: Have you added a reference to Excel or are you using `CreateObject("excel.application")` It could be `xlWhole` so either add `Const xlWhole=1" or change to `LookAt:=1`

Comment: I use CreateObject("Excel.Application"). LookAt:=1 is the solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should still check that FIND actually finds something or you'll get the Error 91 as @Rory said.  `IF NOT findresult IS NOTHING THEN offset from the value ELSE report that nothing was found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With late binding to excel the constants are not defined so use the value 1 in place of `xlWhole`. Consider checking that find returns an object to avoid further errors.

```vb
Sub demo()

    Dim ColumnA As String, ColumnB As String, rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' amend to suit

    ColumnA = InputBox("Please Column A value.")
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets("fsgksdhgks").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ColumnA, LookAt:=1) ' 1=xlWhole
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ColumnA & " not found", vbExclamation
    Else
        ColumnB = rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
        MsgBox ColumnB, vbInformation, ColumnA & "  found at " & rng.Address
    End If

End Sub
```